# When/where to implement FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I've a code (program) working by now, that the uses select input files, outputfolders and then convert to xml.

All variables and methods are inside a class (another file, but this is no problem).

Anyway. I would like to change its behaviour to a hotfolder behaviour ; that way, when some file is added to the folder it'll process based on already implemented methods and do whatever stuff i want.

Okay, so now here comes my question: actually , on Form1.cs all i got is some button_click calls.
Should i place the FileSystemWatcher + OnChanged method inside Form1.Cs or should i place it inside my Classes.cs file (this is the file with all methods, variables, etc - the business logic).
Also, when do i call it ? As soon the form1 is initialized would be best ?
Thanks for any opinion :)

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is an expensive action, people use it when a change of file or folder in hard drive is highly sensitive with current app, you should not use it if not really needed. Based on your previous questions, you're developing a tool that convert a file type to other file type. That is no need for implement for this techicque.

Comment: I've been asked to implement a HotFolder system - so... FileSystemWatcher is my guy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure, do not put the Watcher in your form.

A pattern you can use is something like this:

```
public class DirectoryRefresher : IDisposable
{
    private FileSystemWatcher FileWatcher { get; set; }

    public DirectoryRefresher(string directorypath)
    {
        FileWatcher = SetupFileWatcher(directoryPath);
    }

    protected FileSystemWatcher SetupFileWatcher(string path)
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);

        watcher.Changed += (sender, e) => { DoYourProcessing(e.FullPath); };
        watcher.Created += (sender, e) => { DoYourProcessing(e.FullPath); };
        watcher.Deleted += (sender, e) => { DoYourProcessing(e.FullPath); };

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        return watcher;
    }

    public void DoYourProcessing(string filePath)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileWatcher != null)
            {
                FileWatcher.Dispose();
                FileWatcher = null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }

}
```

When you know the folder, you just instantiate a DirectoryRefresher. When you want to stop it, you just Dispose() it.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to fix it but i couln't:  if i use juse it this way i won't access my vars on the parent class (they're protected). If i create a new instance of their content inside this class, it'll receive a new copy without its data.

Comment: It's hard for me to grasp your full scenario without seeing some code. In case a separate class doesn't fit your use, you can attach the FileSystemWatcher to your "parent" class, which, AFAICT, contains all your application logic. Just keep the FileWatcher property, the Setup method and insert the DoYourProcessing, reusing your existing logic.